# Angular extended class constructor overloading

Tags: angular, constructor, httpclient

I have following class extended to NbLoginComponent in @nebular/auth library. I need to add a constructor to HttpClient to use http. But cannot add a constructor because the NbLoginComponent default constructor expecting 4 parameters that i haven't. I have added those parameters but no success. Can some one tell me another way to initialize HttpClient without using constructor.

Following is my code

```js
export class NgxLoginComponent extends NbLoginComponent {
  protected service: NbAuthService;
  protected options: {};
  protected cd: ChangeDetectorRef;
  protected router: Router;
  constructor(
    service: NbAuthService,
    options: {},
    cd: ChangeDetectorRef,
    router: Router,
    private http: HttpClient
  ) {
    super(service, options, cd, router);
  }
  }
```

The first four arguments in the constructor are required by the default constructor of NbLoginComponent. I need another way to initialize HttpClient.

Comment: can you create a stackblitz demo showing this issue?

Answer (score 2):

You should use  @Inject(NB_AUTH_OPTIONS) protected options, instead of options: {}, for example:

```
export class NgxLoginComponent extends NbLoginComponent {
  protected service: NbAuthService;
  protected options: {};
  protected cd: ChangeDetectorRef;
  protected router: Router;
  constructor(
    service: NbAuthService,
    @Inject(NB_AUTH_OPTIONS) protected options,
    cd: ChangeDetectorRef,
    router: Router,
    private http: HttpClient
  ) {
    super(service, options, cd, router);
  }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using the constructor i have used following and it resolve my issue.

```js
http = new HttpClient(
    new HttpXhrBackend({ build: () => new XMLHttpRequest() })
  );
```